# Why can you call the base version of a method from the override version of the same method

Tags: c#

I'm confused why C# is letting me do this:

**base class**

```
public virtual void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{

}
```

**derived class**

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

This code works with no problem. But how is it calling base.OnResultExecuted when that is the method I am overriding?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is confusing? Plenty of cases in my own code I wish to add functionality that only applies to an inherited class (whilst still requiring the inherited member to use the base function)

Comment: say you just want to add logging to the method.  You'd override it, do your logging, then call the base method.  It's pretty common functionality

Comment: "Overriding" doesn't mean "overwriting". The base method still exists, it is just not exposed in the derived type.

Comment: because this is how inheritance is meant to work

Comment: It's legal because Microsoft wanted it that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why this is useful is pretty obvious.  "How?" is less obvious, but also interesting.

The MSIL encoding in which .NET code is stored has two instructions for a method call:

- `call`
- `callvirt`

The difference is that when `callvirt` is used with a virtual method, it doesn't call the method indicated.  Instead, it maps the method indicated to a slot in the object class's vtable, finds the actual implementation belonging to the object's class, and calls that version.

(For non-virtual methods, `callvirt` just adds a null check and then directly calls the indicated method).

The `call` instruction doesn't use the vtable.  It simply calls the method named in the MSIL.  When you use the `base` keyword in C#, the compiler generates a `call` instruction, so that the exact method provided by the base class is used, and not the overriding method linked in the vtable.

This behavior is [documented on MSDN for the `call` opcode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.call.aspx)

> It is valid to call a virtual method using `call` (rather than `callvirt`); this indicates that the method is to be resolved using the class specified by *method* rather than as specified dynamically from the object being invoked.

Answer (score 4):

This is a specific feature. Using `base` allows you to access functionality in the base class from the inheritor. [See MSDN for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx):

> The base keyword is used to access members of the base class from
>   within a derived class:
>
> - Call a method on the base class that has been
>     overridden by another method.
> - Specify which base-class constructor
>     should be called when creating instances of the derived class.

This is probably more often used with constructors, but it can be handy for overriding a method as well. Perhaps you want to add more functionality to what the base class does - this would save you from re-creating that functionality in the inheritor.

Comment: This doesn't really describe "how".

Answer (score 1):

If your `Base` class has an implementation on it and you want to use the default implementation in your child class then you call `base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);`

```
public class BaseClass
{
  protected virtual void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext resultExecutedContext)
  {
    // Do something like save something to the database
  }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
 protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext resultExecutedContext)
 {
   // Or override the default implementation and do not save it to the database
 }

 protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext resultExecutedContext)
 {
  // I could either save it to the database
   base.OnResultExecuted(resultExecutedContext);
   // Then do something else after the base implementation OnResultExecuted.
 }
}
```

The dual method is compile error but I'm just showing the difference between the two implementation. This is one of the many cases you want to use `base` vs `not calling base`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an OO tool.  Take a look at some standard design patterns.  Specifically, a [decorator pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)